# Calling API through Alamofire but having some issue

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am calling api through Alamofire and I am passing request params perfectly. I have checked that but still I am not getting response. I am getting success message but don't get response data. Below is my code,

```
let API = "http://siestalaminates.com/admin/index.php/Webservice/getcategorybybrandid"
let subcate = ["brand_id": brandid] as [String:Any]
        Alamofire.request(API, method: .post, parameters: subcate ).responseJSON
            {
                response in
                //printing response
                print(response)
                let result = response.result
                // let obj=result
                if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{
                    if let subdata = dict["data"]{
                        self.subcatelist = subdata as! [AnyObject]
                        self.subcategory_collection.reloadData()

                    }
                }
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
```

Pass Brand id dynamically::

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        ///print("==>",cateid[indexPath.row] as NSString)

            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProductsubcategoryViewController") as! ProductsubcategoryViewController

            vc.brandid = (self.brandid[indexPath.row] as NSString) as String?


            self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

If I pass brand_id statically then I am getting response but when I pass it dynamically then it pass perfectly but not getting response.

Comment: Make sure (self.brandid[indexPath.row] as NSString) as String? is not null. You can use Alamofire Activity logger to print the network logs neatly.https://github.com/konkab/AlamofireNetworkActivityLogger

Comment: yes i was checked it is not null i am getting brand id from that line

Comment: Do u cast subcate as [String:Any] when u are statically call the API?

Comment: yes its [String: Any] when i pass statically

Comment: I think your id is in form of optional(someId)? can you check this one ?

Comment: If your getting success response and your id is not options(someid) then ask your backend developer for fix.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan i didn't get it please explain what u want to say

Comment: use print() before alamofire get calls 
let subcate = ["brand_id": brandid] as [String:Any]
print(subcate)
        Alamofire.request(API, method: .post, parameters: subcate ).responseJSON
            {
and post result in comment.

Comment: yes it is optional @AbuUlHassan

Comment: i have posted answer below it will work fine :) happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the following line:

```
   let subcate = ["brand_id": brandid] as [String:Any]
```

With:

```
   let subcate = ["brand_id": brandid!] as [String:Any]
```

It seems only issue you have is optional and required values. I think you're not good with optional and required chaining.

Comment: i hope you will accept the answer ;) if it is working :D

Comment: thanks 
now make it crash safe using  if let :) or guard let so that in any case in future id is null your app should not crash.